# Using SoapClient in php in mule

Tags: php, soap, mule

I am using the following php script in mule. When i am running this php file individually(through wamp) i am able to get the required output.

```
<?php

$client1=new SoapClient('example/v2_soap?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 120));
$username = '******';
$password = '******';

//retreive session id from login
$session = $client1->login(
  array(
    'username' => $username,
    'apiKey' => $password,
  )
);

$result= $client1->catalogProductInfo(
  array(
    'sessionId' => $session->result,
    'productId' => 1,
  )
);

print_r($result);

return $result;
?>
```

But i want to run the following script through mule. So when i am running it through mule i am getting the following error.

Root Exception stack trace:

```
com.caucho.quercus.QuercusErrorException: eval::5: Fatal Error: 'SoapClient' is an unknown class name.
at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.error(Env.java:4480)
at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.error(Env.java:4399)
at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.createErrorException(Env.java:4130)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

It says SoapClient is an unknown class. What is the problem here?

Do i have to include some SoapClient here? If so where can i find it. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if mule supports php extensions, but that's what it seems by the error. You could try downloading [nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) into your project,
which doesn't require any php extension. The syntaxis is a little bit different though, but shouldn't be harder to adapt your code.

For what it's worth, this is a simple example of a soap request using nusoap (taken from here http://www.richardkmiller.com/files/msnsearch_nusoap.html):

```
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$request = array('Request' => array(
                'AppID' => 'MSN_SEARCH_API_KEY',
                'Query' => 'Seinfeld',
                'CultureInfo' => 'en-US',
                'SafeSearch' => 'Strict',
                'Flags' => '',
                'Location' => '',
                'Requests' => array(
                        'SourceRequest' => array(
                                'Source' => 'Web',
                                'Offset' => 0,
                                'Count' => 50,
                                'ResultFields' => 'All'))));

$soapClient = new soapclient("http://soap.search.msn.com/webservices.asmx?wsdl", false);
$result = $soapClient->call("Search", $request);
print_r($result);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I understand there seems to be a problem with running the soap client inside quercus (rather than Mule).

However instead of focusing on it I would suggest to take a look to the CXF client and the Web services consumer. You are running inside of Mule a powerful opensource ESB, there is no need to write a php script to consume a service, you have all that functinality already present.